# How can I update Lead satus field to a Lead which remained NOT Converted

Tags: apex

I would like to know how to be able to update custom status Lead field to all the Leads which for some reason remained NOT converted to Account?

I would like to be able to set all NOT converted Leads to particular status. Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

UPDATE

```
List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT company, website, status__c, IsConverted FROM Lead where company =:companyName AND website =:accountObjWebs];
```

and check

```
boolean isLeadConverted = ld.IsConverted; 
if (!isLeadConverted) { 
   ld.Status__c = 'Existing Deal'; 
} 
update ld.Status__c;
```

The problem is that even though I update the Status__c in database table Lead for some reason the field Status__c remains not updated.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: how you will identify which one is not converted, do you set any flag to true which identify not converted leads?

Comment: In order to determine which Lead is not converted I use the following

List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT company, website, status__c, IsConverted FROM Lead where company =:companyName AND website =:accountObjWebs];
and check boolean isLeadConverted = ld.IsConverted; 
if (!isLeadConverted) {
ld.Status__c = 'Existing Deal';
}
update ld.Status__c;
The problem is that even though I update the Status__c in database table Lead for some reason the field Status__c remains not updated.

Comment: That is the problem I'm trying to solve. Could you please help and advise how to make the Status__c filed become updated in the Lead table?

Comment: You can add new status in lead and set that value using update call. can you update this question with your code.

Comment: the `update ld.status__c` won't compile - you need to update a list of leads

Comment: I am aware that ld.status__c will not compile that is why I used a list of leads. The code is available in https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000005JXnIAM. There I have explained what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Could you please suggest how to resolve the problem described in https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000005JXnIAM